# Wanted: 100 BaseTX devices without Auto Mdix

Tags: ethernet

Most 100 Base TX ethernet devices today support auto mdix. However I need a device (ethernet nic, router, usb ethernet adapter, ...) where it is either possible to permanently (via software/drivers is not enough) disable auto mdix (by desoldering a pin maybe?) or where auto mdix is not even implemented. But I'm not sure if such a thing even exists. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you need to disable Auto-MDX?

Comment: Because for my (security) application it is required that TX will always stay TX and RX will always stay RX. It goes a bit in the direction of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidirectional_network

Comment: You are not going to be able to do what you want with modern, standard network equipment. The article to which you link has a list of vendors for unidirectional data transfer equipment. You should research the products of those vendors.

Comment: Could you point out why it is not possible? Of course I could buy a commercial solution which, however, usually cost a fortune. But, also refering to your other comment, I have some other means to ensure unidirectional data transfer. Commercial solution use fiber optics for this. There are also some hackish solutions which require e.g. three media converters. My idea was to only use one converter, connect the RX and TX fiber connection with one cable. Plug in a spliced ethernet cable which has on the end facing away from the device two RJ45 jacks. One for the TX side and one for the RX side.

Comment: The Auto-MDX is built into the controller chip logic, and you need software to disable it. Some older devices had a physical switch to handle this, but the current hardware has placed it into the controller chips. This actually has nothing to do with uni-directional communications.

Comment: So only two wires go into such a jack. The TX and RX jacks of the spliced side are plugged into two different computers. So I could copy safely a file from PC1 to PC2 without anything going back. But theoretically, through the auto mdix feature, some malware could remap the pins on PC1 or 2, so that TX becomes RX and vice versa. Hence data transfer in the opposite directions would also be possible making the whole device useless for a security application. So something without auto mdix would be desirable.   Edit: My two comments belong together. I was not fast enough with typing ...

Comment: I know that some chips e.g. the dp83848 have a specific pin for auto mdix but I don't know if desoldering this pin would disable auto mdix or what would happen at all.

Comment: A switch or router will not bring up an interface in such a scenario. Both the interface and line protocol (from receive) need to be up for the interface to work. That is why there is dedicated hardware for this sort of thing. I think you are seeing something involving a hub, which is really just another layer-1 device like the wire. I think this question is really off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Go buy some junk at a garage sale or on sleaze-bay. Plenty of hubs (and a few switches, perhaps) were made this way ~20 years ago.[image: DS108] Look for a switch to make one port "uplink" (as seen on the right of this picture) and you're probably looking at the junque you want....

Comment: This looks good :). Do you know some other (non-router/switch) devices? Or some means to recognize a device which does not support auto mdix?

Comment: @nashad, even old equipment which does not do Auto-MDX will still allow bi-directional communication. The article to which you link is about uni-directional communication. Product or resource recommendations are specifically off-topic. You should look at the list of vendors at the bottom of the article.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to test is to get two identical devices, plug a straight cable between them and see if they link up.

I suspect you are looking for older hardware. I'm pretty sure the secondary card in my office desktop (which came out of a collegues junk box) doesn't do auto MDI-X but I don't have the model number handy right now.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to satisfy the requirement on the hardware level. There are platforms which support disabling Auto MDI-X.

For example: Cisco IOS offers the `no mdix auto` command. Junos offers the `no-auto-mdix` command. Still, I recommend to look up the specifiation because you may get a device which does not run the original image anymore. Look for a feature navigator on the vendor's homepage.

Comment: According to the question, using the `no mdix auto` command, or any software solution is not good enough. This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: In that case the question should be censored because it doesn't leave any option besides buying a device that doesn't support Auto MDI-X at all. So what's left? Product recommendations.

Comment: I do think the question is heading toward being off-topic. You can flag the question.

Comment: I won't be the one. I think it's quite helpful to have unsolved questions because they might show why a question cannot be answered. Please, let's give the question more time.